# EDT not working with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

In iOS, I am using a `NSDateFormatter` with the DateFormat `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z`.

The String `Sat, 29 Aug 2015 12:34:36 EDT` does not work and gives back `nil` when given to the function .dateFromString(). The exact same string with GMT (`Sat, 29 Aug 2015 12:34:36 GMT`) gives me the correct date, though.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you get if you use stringFromDate to convert a date to a string using your date formatter with the time zone set to EDT? I looked it up and it seems like what you're doing should work, but maybe the time zone code is something other than "EDT".

Comment: I tried `let formatter = NSDateFormatter(); formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"; print(formatter.dateFromString("Sat, 29 Aug 2015 12:34:36 EDT"))` and got `Optional(2015-08-29 16:34:36 +0000)`, not nil. What's your locale? Edit your question to include code that demonstrates the problem in a playground.

Comment: Just tested it in several locations: In the simulator (with the same code) , on the mac and in playgrounds it does work. In iOS (9.1; iPhone 6) , I get nil. (See my answer below for context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that the locale I was using wasn't a usual one. I live in Germany and use English as my system language, so the Locale was one with the identifier `en_DE`. Both `de_DE` and `en_US` work with the usual Time Zones (Like `EDT`), but the unusual `en_DE` doesn't work with all of them. So the fix was to use `en_US` as the locale.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this should work, I'm in New Zealand but set locale to "EDT"

```
let string = "Sat, 29 Aug 2015 12:34:36 EDT"

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EDT")
formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z"

let localDate = formatter.dateFromString(string)
```

Comment: "EDT" is a timezone, not a locale. This makes no sense. A locale would be something like "en_NZ" for New Zealand English, for example.